# Can we calculate the fastest passage of time?

Tags: spacetime, time

I recently watched one of the several "time causes gravity" videos on YouTube. It led me to a question. Simplifying the universe just a bit and assuming we can represent the passage of time as a "velocity" (V<sub>T</sub>), then we know:

$$\lim \limits_{V_x,y,z \to c} V_t = 0$$

Said another way, when an object's velocity in space is equal to the speed of light, the "velocity of time" is equal to zero. My question, then, is this:

$$\lim \limits_{V_x,y,z \to 0} V_t = ?$$

Said another way, what is the maximum "velocity" of time if an object becomes absolutely motionless in space?

The idea that there is such a maximum appears supported by the idea that clocks move faster the further they are away from Earth's gravity well. If I'm oversimplifying all this properly, the idea is that the force of gravity represents a "velocity" such that the further away one gets from a gravity well, the lower the overall velocity of the object, and the faster time passes. (And this is complicated by the rotation and orbit of the Earth, the orbit of the solar system, the motion of the galaxy, etc.).

Nevertheless, is it possible to calculate the fastest possible passage of time?

NOTE:

I understand that the passage of time most likely must be expressed in our reference frame. A human on a theoretical space ship traveling up to the speed of light and back again (and ignoring a whole lotta stuff) would perceive the passage of time as "normal" even though it's not passing at $V_x,y,z = c$. So, I expect an answer to my question having to be expressed in the context of Earth's reference frame — but I could be wrong.

Comment: So you are comparing relative times. The proper time “velocity” is always the same for any reference frame. And I believe it is essentially c. There’s no limit to how large a relative time ratio can be.

Comment: @geshel I'll take your word for it. I'm not a physicist. However, telling me that "c" is the time "velocity" literally makes no sense whatsoever as time, even expressed as a "velocity" wouldn't be in m/s, would it? My first guess/assumption would be that it would have to be expressed as a percentage, where V(t) at seal level on Earth would be 100% and an object traveling in space at V(x,y,z)=c would result in 0%. The working theory is that at V(x,y,z)=0, V(t) > 100%.

Comment: The only sensible definition of the “velocity of time” (which is not a concept in mainstream physics) is $V_t=dt/dt$. So that tells you its value is 1. Time “moves” at one second per second.

Comment: @G.Smith If memory serves, the clocks aboard the GPS satellites must be periodically adjusted because they run as a different "velocity" of time than seal-level, Earth - suggesting that it would be $V_t = dt_1/dt_2$.

Comment: That would be a “relative time velocity”, otherwise known as a time dilation factor. It makes no sense to denote it as $V_t$. Each clock runs at one second per second. Each measures the *other* clock as running at a different rate.

Comment: Sorry yes my comment about it being c was vague. And it is again really more of a relative time thing - the idea being that you are always moving through spacetime at some speed - let’s call it c - and the vector relative to some other observer will have a space component and a time component to it. Either of those may be zero so long as the magnitude of the vector is c.

Comment: @geshel OK, so if I understand you, it means that (in the nomenclature of the question), $V_x,y,z,t = c$ in all circumstances? The spacetime "velocity" of an object is always *c*?

Comment: I was about to write that I am only sure if that in an SR context, and not sure if that holds for Gen Relativity. But of course that is the origin of your question! Sorry about that.